# Is it possible to use *= operator together with round() function

Tags: php, operators, rounding

I often need to use fractional modificators for my variables. Like this:

```
$var *= 1.5;
```

Yet I need the oputput to be rounded, so I need to use:

```
$var = round($var * 1.5);
```

Is is no big deal, but every single time I can not use the `*=` operator, and I need to write `round()`. Is there a shrotcut for this?

Comment: No, there's no shortcut. Also `rand` or `round`?

Comment: `round` - my mistake, fixed it.
If You are sure about Your answer, please post it and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `$var *= 1.5;` is a shortcut for `$var = $var * 1.5;` this means that you can't inject any function call here. So, `$var = round($var * 1.5);` cannot be changed using `*=` notation.

As a solution you can use a user-defined function:

```
$var = multiplyAndRound($var, 1.5);
function multiplyAndRound($var, $multiplier) {
    return round($var * $multiplier);
}
// or with passing by refrence
$var = 1.3;
multiplyAndRound($var, 1.5);
function multiplyAndRound(&$var, $multiplier) {
    $var = round($var * $multiplier);
}
```

But I don't think that this can be called "shortcut".